# Difference between Detail size and Resolution

Tags: sculpting

What is the difference or what change made from 2.78 and 2.79 and how it works in the sculpting under **Dyntopo**

In 2.78 switching to Dyntopo -> constant detail -> I get option **Detail Size**

&

In 2.79 switching to Dyntopo -> constant detail -> I get option **Resolution**

What is the difference and how it work.